# Needed switch bandwidth for USB Type C D+/D- over-voltage protection

Tags: over-voltage-protection, usb-pd

I am currently trying to add over-voltage protection to a USB C PD receptacle (with BC1.2 support.) As the SBU pins aren't used, I'd like to protect the D+/D- pins from short to VBUS.

The TI reference designs use the TPD6S300, routing D+/D- through the SBU protection circuit. The lead time of TPD6S300 is >50 weeks so I'm looking for a replacement.

What is the needed switch bandwidth for this to work? ICs I've found supporting this:

- TPD6S300 @ 1GHz
- NX20P0407 @ 1.5GHz

What is the lower limit for the bandwidth? (I'd like to use DPO2036 which offers only 600MHz, or anything else that's not a wlcs package.)

Comment: USB-C can transport USB 1, 1.1, 2 FS, 2 HS on the D+/D- lines. Which USB speed do you need? That alone defines the bandwidth.

Comment: It's just for the BC1.2 support. Which is definitely USB 2. But I don't know whether LS, FS or HS.

Comment: ah, well, the USB PD protocol is really pretty low speed and robust.